# Populating an NSPopUpButtonCell with string values

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbuttoncell

I am trying to populate a NSPopUpButtonCell with a list of strings.  In -(init), I populate an NSArray with the values I want in the PopUp Button.  How do I connect this to the NSArrayController I added in IB?  Does my app delegate need an IBOutlet NSArrayController to connect to or is there a way to bind it?

Also, when I bind the NSArrayController to the NSPopUpButtonCell, do which Content do I bind it to?  Content or Content Values?

jorj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the array controller's Content Array to your controller's array of strings. Bind both the pop-up button cell's [Content](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButtonCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/binding/NSPopUpButtonCell/content) and [Content Values](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButtonCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/binding/NSPopUpButtonCell/contentValues) to your array controller's `arrangedObjects`.

Presumably, you also want to know which of these strings is selected. To do that, bind the pop-up button cell's [Selected Object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButtonCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/binding/NSPopUpButtonCell/selectedObject) (which will be one of the objects in Content) to a property of your controller (the one that owns the original array).

Comment: Select the array controller and press ⌘4.

Comment: Got it.  I had to set my app delegate variable to NSArray instead of NSArrayController (i had been switching back and forth to see which one would work), NOT make it an IBOutlet, bind the NSArrayController in IB to the app delegate, and set the "Model Key Path" to the name of the NSArray in the app delegate.  Thanks!